# How to use geometry from scene file with multiple objects (geometries)?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit, arkit

I have a blender file that I've exported as DAE/collada and then converted to Scenekit's Scene file using Xcode. I'm having trouble using the geometry from the Scene file.

The Scene file ("model.scn") is pretty basic:

- Group (no geometry element)

  - Shape1 (geometry element)
  - Shape2 (geometry element)
  - Shape3 (geometry element)

When I'm trying to use the model, I'm unable to use the combined geometry of the 3 shapes for a SCNGeometry used with SCNPhysicsBody.

I've tried various approaches, but they don't work:

### Approach 1

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/model.scn")!
let node = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Group", recursively: true)!
guard let geo = node.geometry else { return }
// node.geometry is nil so returns here

let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .kinematic, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: geo))
// this is what I need the custom/aggregate geometry for
```

### Approach 2

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/model.scn")!
let geoNode = SCNNode()
let node1 = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Shape1", recursively: true)!
let node2 = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Shape2", recursively: true)!
let node3 = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Shape3", recursively: true)!
geoNode.addChildNode(node1)
geoNode.addChildNode(node2)
geoNode.addChildNode(node3)

// expected geoNode.geometry is not nil, but it is
```

According to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407966-geometry)

> A node can have only one geometry attached to it. To combine geometries so they can be controlled or animated together, create a node with no geometry and add other nodes to it.

But it doesn't appear to be working as the parent node's geometry optional is still nil.

What I'm trying to do should be simple, but I'm going about it the wrong way. I want to use the geometry from my dae/collada/scene file. I do NOT want to use the defaults (cubes, cylinders, pyramids, spheres, torus, etc).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SceneKit will not merge `SCNGeometry` instances automatically for you. To do that you would have to create new `SCNGeometrySource` and `SCNGeometryElement` objects before creating the merged `SCNGeometry`.

The documentation might be a little misleading. What it's trying to say is that if you want to manipulate multiple geometries at the same time, then grouping multiple nodes under a common parent will make things easier as manipulating this single node will affect (translate, rotate, scale) all its child nodes.

Note that in your case you can use [`init(shapes:transforms:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsshape/1508886-init) to explicitly merge multiple `SCNPhysicsShape` instance. Start by creating a shape for each geometry, and then create the combined shape. The `transforms` parameter would be made of the [`transform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1407964-transform) of the nodes grouped under their common parent.

Comment: Thanks, for my specific use case, I was able to resolve using `init(node:options:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsshape/1508889-init

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution in your case, is to import the original `.dae` model into Autodesk Maya and merge all the individual parts into a mono-model. Select all the individual parts in Maya viewport and choose from the main menu <kbd>Mesh</kbd> – <kbd>Combine</kbd> (Modeling menu set).

After that apply <kbd>Edit</kbd> – <kbd>Delete By Type</kbd> – <kbd>History</kbd> and export your model as `.dae`.